# € symbol rendering as â‚¬2

Tags: mysql, html, linux, symbols

Unusual problem here: I have an app that uses a text file which contains a few '€' symbols as well as other text in a text file to populate a mysql database. When rendered locally, the € symbol looks fine, but on the linux server and out on the web in html, it looks like this in some browsers:

â‚¬2

can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: Do your HTTP response headers contain the correct `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding`? E.g.: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: I found the W3C articles on character encoding useful, see http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/ and the others articles linked from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an UTF-8 encoding type on your file and make sure you add a content-type `meta` tag to your page:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: @Paul - glad to be of help ! :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me in all cases... I'm on a Windows 7 machine, using WAMP server. In Firefox & IE: no problem, but Chrome still renders €  as â‚¬. I have exactly the mentioned meta tag in the source.The response header contains amongst others "Content-Type:text/html", so that's good I guess. Anyone any clue why Chrome doesn't render this right?

Comment: @Myself: there was content before the beginning of the HTML. When I took care of that, it suddenly did work. May be Chrome ignored the META-tags when output occurs before <html>. Anyhow, problem solved :)

Answer (score 4):

Set the charset in the headers or a `<META>` element to UTF-8 so that it isn't processed as CP1250.

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing your text (.txt) file as a text and not HTML in browsers window, setting

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**will not do the job as you are dealing with text file**,

so tags will not be "hidden", plus it may potentially (even most likely) send garbage to mysql database you are trying to populate (e.g. by auto-harvesting posted online file).

So, if in browser window instead of:

> € 123.39

you are seeing

> â‚¬2 123.39

problem is not with quality of your text file, but with the way browser handles encoding.

If you need to copy and paste displayed file and "â‚¬2" is in the way,
**try simply** setting your browser default encoding to unicode (UTF-8).

In FF you want to do it here:

> Tools-> Options-> Content (tab)-> Fonts&Colors-> Advanced-> Default Char. Encoding

Once there select UTF-8 encoding.

**Remember thou** that sometimes page reload may not be enough to see changes, due to browser cache. In such case, restart your browser.